# threading.lock forcing threads to run sequentially?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, race-condition, locks

My dummy script utilizes two functions, one that adds 1 and one that subtracts 1.
I am attempting to run each function 1000000  times asynchronously with threads, and using locks to prevent race conditions.

However, I have noticed that when my locks are used within the `for loop` itself, 
the same thread will run until the loop is finished, making me believe the threads are running synchronously.

Here is how my script looks:

```
master_count = 0
trials = 1000
import threading

def add_count():
    global master_count
    for i in range(trials):
        with lock:
            print(threading.current_thread().getName())
            master_count += 1



def subtract_count():
    global master_count
    for i in range(trials):
        with lock:
            print(threading.current_thread().getName())

            master_count -= 1



lock = threading.Lock()

t1 = threading.Thread(target = add_count, name = 'add1' )
t2 = threading.Thread(target = add_count, name = 'add2' )
t3 = threading.Thread(target = subtract_count, name = 'subtract1' )
t4 = threading.Thread(target = subtract_count, name = 'subtract2' )

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()


t4.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t1.join()

print(master_count)
```

I am seeing this outputted to the python shell (10 trials):

```
add1
add1
add1
add1
add1
add1
add1
add1
add1
add1
add2
add2
add2
add2
add2
add2
add2
add2
add2
add2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract2
subtract1
subtract1
subtract1
subtract1
subtract1
subtract1
subtract1
subtract1
subtract1
subtract1
```

I would imagine that if the script was running async, I would see a mixture of thread names instead of this ordered output.

I am attempted this within a `While` loop as well, but I am running into the same problem.

So is it in fact running synchronously? If so how can I make it run async with locks.

Thank you.

Comment: Your sample size of 10 is too small to see "interweaving" (nevertheless `subtract2` executes before `subtract1` though it's started later). Before you start the second thread the first one could've finished already. Increase `trials` to 1,000 and you'll see the threads executing in parallel.

Comment: Thank you. Increasing the trial size to 100,000, I have noticed that  threads come in sets of 1000 or so, meaning `add1` will show up 1000 times followed by `add2` 1000 times (or so), followed by `subtract1` and then the cycle will repeat in any order. So it seems that the same thread is given priority to reenter the lock? I assumed it would be more "messy".

Comment: I guess that really depends on how your OS schedules CPU time for the threads (e.g. 1 ms round robin). Might appear "batch-like" since the workload is so small that it can perform lots of function calls in a small time interval.

Comment: Ah thank you! I am using Windows 7.